# JoinS Sobre la misma Tabla con Valores Null

Tags: sql, join

Estos intentando realizar dos JOINS para emparejar la información de dos tablas, la primera tabla contiene un catálogo de artículos.

```
id_art      desc      
------------------------
A1          Articulo A1
A2          Articulo A2
A3          Articulo A3
A4          Articulo A4
A5          Articulo A5
```

La segunda tabla contiene puntos de re orden de la mayoría de los artículos por sucursal.

```
id          id_art      max     pro     min
----------------------------------------------
01          A1          0       2       5 
02          A1          1       2       4
02          A2          1       2       6
01          A3          1       3       5
02          A3          2       4       6
01          A5          0       2       3
```

Lo que necesito es que el resultado de la Query me dé lo siguiente

```
id      suc         max     pro     min     suc         max     pro     min
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1      01          0       2       5       02          1       2       4
A2      NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    02          1       2       6
A3      01          1       3       5       02          2       4       6
A5      01          0       2       3       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Actualmente la Query que he generado solo me da como resultado artículos que tengan registro en la sucursal 01 y 02, omitiendo los registros individuales

```
id      suc         max     pro     min     suc         max     pro     min
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1      01          0       2       5       02          1       2       4
A3      01          1       3       5       02          2       4       6
```

Estoy tratando de organizarlo con la siguiente Query:

```
SELECT 
a.id_art,
r1.suc,
r1.max,
r1.pro,
r1.min,
r2.suc,
r2.max,
r2.pro,
r2.min 
FROM articulos a
RIGHT JOIN(SELECT suc,max,pro,min FROM MMR
    WHERE suc='01'
) r1 ON r1.id_art=a.id_art
RIGHT JOIN(SELECT suc,max,pro,min FROM MMR
    WHERE suc='02'
) r2 ON r2.id_art=a.id_art
ORDER BY a.id_art
```

Agradezco su apoyo, estoy algo perdido ya que es la primera vez que trabajo con SQL , gracias.

Comment: te falta un group by por la que quieres agrupar que seria articulo y sucursal

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos usas?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando un `RIGHT JOIN` donde deberías estar usando un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
a.id_art,
r1.suc,
r1.max,
r1.pro,
r1.min,
r2.suc,
r2.max,
r2.pro,
r2.min 
FROM articulos a
LEFT JOIN(SELECT suc,max,pro,min FROM MMR
    WHERE suc='01'
) r1 ON r1.id_art=a.id_art
LEFT JOIN(SELECT suc,max,pro,min FROM MMR
    WHERE suc='02'
) r2 ON r2.id_art=a.id_art
ORDER BY a.id_art
```

Personalmente, modificaría la forma de hacer el join para evitar usar tablas derivadas innecesariamente:

```
SELECT 
a.id_art,
r1.suc,
r1.max,
r1.pro,
r1.min,
r2.suc,
r2.max,
r2.pro,
r2.min 
FROM articulos a
LEFT JOIN MMR r1
  ON r1.id_art=a.id_art
 AND r1.suc='01'
LEFT JOIN MMR r2
  ON r2.id_art=a.id_art
 AND r2.suc='02'
ORDER BY a.id_art
```

Otra manera de escribir la consulta que te evita hacer 2 joins es de la forma siguiente:

```
select a.id_art,
       case(when m.suc = '01' then m.suc end) as suc01,
       case(when m.suc = '01' then m.max end) as max01,
       case(when m.suc = '01' then m.pro end) as pro01,
       case(when m.suc = '01' then m.min end) as min01,
       case(when m.suc = '02' then m.suc end) as suc02,
       case(when m.suc = '02' then m.max end) as max02,
       case(when m.suc = '02' then m.pro end) as pro02,
       case(when m.suc = '02' then m.min end) as min02
  from articulos a
  left join mmr m
    on m.id_art = a.id_art
 group by a.id_art
 order by a.id_art
```

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de que 01 y 02 sean fijos.

```
SELECT 
    Art.id_art,
    ArtSuc.suc,
    ArtSuc.min,
    ArtSuc.pro,
    ArtSuc.max,
    ArtSuc2.suc,
    ArtSuc2.min,
    ArtSuc2.pro,
    ArtSuc2.max
FROM 
    articulos Art 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT suc,max,pro,min FROM MMR) ArtSuc ON 
        Art.id_art = ArtSuc.id_art AND ArtSuc.id = '01'
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT suc,max,pro,min FROM MMR) ArtSuc2 ON 
        Art.id_art = ArtSuc2.id_art AND ArtSuc2.id = '02'
WHERE
    ArtSuc.id IS NOT null OR ArtSuc2.id IS NOT NULL
```